# Whose destructor is this one?

Tags: c++

In the code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    std::string a;
    int b;

    S(const S&) = default;
    S(S&&) = default;
    S& operator=(const S&) = default;
    S& operator=(S&&) = default; // not required here but should be added for completeness

    ~S() {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

S f(S arg) {
    S s0{};
    S s1(s0); //s1 {s0}; in the book
    s1 = arg;
    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    S s3{"tool",42};
    f(s3);
}
```

I get the following output (I commented the output with my reasonings):

```
 42 //???
 0  // s0 is destroyed
tool 42 // arg is destroyed
tool 42 // return value of f() is destroyed
tool 42 // s3 is destroyed
```

whose destructor is the one which outputs 42?? I can't understand it

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Can you tell us which platform, compiler you are using and the compilation command line ?

Comment: [cnr](http://ideone.com/qDoRSg).

Comment: I get everything reproduced except the "42" in the first line. You have definitely used C++11 there, the whole "Default" business....
language:
C++11
created:
0 seconds ago
visibility:
public 

Share or Embed source code <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/wWQcUm" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: Also can't reproduce - seems fine to me. I get the output I expect not what is shown above.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23646fe53ce8ede2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic variables are destroyed in reverse order of declaration, so the destructor indicated is the destructor of `s1`.

The reason it takes the value `{"", 42}` at that point in the program is that the return value of `f` is being initialized by move construction; that is, `s1` is being treated as an xvalue.  This follows from the rule in **[class.copy]**/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
>   object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to
>   select the constructor for the copy is ﬁrst performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

Comment: It is interesting to note that this behaviour is triggered for example by the G++ `-fno-elide-constructors` option, which disables this specific optimisation.